# How to calculate the count of column values less than 95 on each row on pandas pivot table

Tags: pandas

I am new to pandas pivot tables, how to get the count of column values less than 95 for a row on pandas pivot table

```
date                   2015-09-26 2015-09-27 2015-09-28 2015-09-29   
bts_name                                                                 
0001_Durgacomplex_NBSNL           94.45      98.99      93.24       92.3   
0002_Shivanagar_area_Bdr          100        100        94.45        100   
0003_Old_city_Bidar               98.99        94.45        100        100   
0004_Bidar_Mw_Station             94.45       98.99        100        100   
0005_Bidri_colony                 100        94.45       100        98.99
```

The output should be:

```
date                   2015-09-26 2015-09-27 2015-09-28 2015-09-29        cnt
bts_name                                                                 
0001_Durgacomplex_NBSNL           94.45      98.99      93.24       92.3   3
0002_Shivanagar_area_Bdr          100        100        94.45        100   1
0003_Old_city_Bidar               98.99        94.45        100        100  1 
0004_Bidar_Mw_Station             94.45       98.99        100        100   1
0005_Bidri_colony                 100        94.45       100        98.99   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the entire df, this will produce a boolean mask against the whole array, you can then `sum` row-wise, this will convert `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`:

```
In [7]:
df['count'] = (df < 95).sum(axis=1)
df

Out[7]:
                          2015-09-26  2015-09-27  2015-09-28  2015-09-29  \
0001_Durgacomplex_NBSNL        94.45       98.99       93.24       92.30   
0002_Shivanagar_area_Bdr      100.00      100.00       94.45      100.00   
0003_Old_city_Bidar            98.99       94.45      100.00      100.00   
0004_Bidar_Mw_Station          94.45       98.99      100.00      100.00   
0005_Bidri_colony             100.00       94.45      100.00       98.99   

                          count  
0001_Durgacomplex_NBSNL       3  
0002_Shivanagar_area_Bdr      1  
0003_Old_city_Bidar           1  
0004_Bidar_Mw_Station         1  
0005_Bidri_colony             1
```

Here is what the boolean mask looks like:

```
In [8]:
df < 95

Out[8]:
                         2015-09-26 2015-09-27 2015-09-28 2015-09-29
0001_Durgacomplex_NBSNL        True      False       True       True
0002_Shivanagar_area_Bdr      False      False       True      False
0003_Old_city_Bidar           False       True      False      False
0004_Bidar_Mw_Station          True      False      False      False
0005_Bidri_colony             False       True      False      False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [28]:
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda x : np.sum(x < 95) , axis = 1)
df
Out[28]:
                          2015-09-26  2015-09-27   2015-09-28   2015-09-29  count
0001_Durgacomplex_NBSNL     94.45      98.99         93.24          92.30   3
0002_Shivanagar_area_Bdr    100.00     100.00        94.45          100.00  1
0003_Old_city_Bidar         98.99      94.45         100.00         100.00  1
0004_Bidar_Mw_Station       94.45      98.99         100.00         100.00  1
0005_Bidri_colony           100.00     94.45         100.00         98.99   1
```